# Creating an ApiGatewayV2 HTTP API Integration with Subtype SQS-SendMessage Fails with 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, aws-http-api

I'm using serverless@3.23.0 to deploy my services, and I'm looking at setting up an HTTP API Proxy to an SQS Service.

I've handled this previously through this [plugin - serverless-apigateway-service-proxy](https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy). Unfortunately this sets up the proxy through a REST API. I don't need all the features from a REST API, so I'm looking at setting up a HTTP API Proxy to SQS.

I've used these resources to help me set up:

- https://blog.deleu.dev/receiving-sqs-messages-via-api-gateway/
- https://awsteele.com/blog/2021/09/06/api-gateway-http-apis-and-sqs-messageattributes.html

But I'm consistently getting a 400 error

```bash
Operation: SQS-SendMessage is not supported. (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400;
```

Here's the snippet for the Integration.

```yaml
    Integration:
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
      Properties:
        ApiId: ${param:HttpAPIRef}
        IntegrationSubtype: SQS-SendMessage
        IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
        ConnectionType: INTERNET
        PayloadFormatVersion: 1.0
        CredentialsArn: !GetAtt HttpApiRole.Arn
        RequestParameters:
          QueueUrl: !Ref Queue
          MessageBody: random+text
```

I successfully created an Integration through the AWS Console and the aws cli. This is the only workaround. But it's a pain to maintain as you might see

1. Create the integration on the Console or CLI
2. Reference the integration id through custom parameters

A pain when referencing across different environments
Any idea why I would get this error through Cloudfromation?

Also, any way I can debug this further? I'm fairly new to AWS, so I'm learning as I'm going :)

Here's a screenshot of the error on AWS Console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue!

PayloadFormatVersion should be a string.

```
PayloadFormatVersion: 1.0 -> PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message doesn't match your `Resource` configuration. The stack from the second link actually works, so you must be creating a problem in some other way, or aren't looking at the latest error for the stack.

I just tried this stack and it 100% works:

```yaml
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Api
    Properties:
      ProtocolType: HTTP
      Name: sqsdemo

  Stage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Stage
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      StageName: $default
      AutoDeploy: true

  Queue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue

  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              Service: apigateway.amazonaws.com
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: sqssend
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: sqs:SendMessage
                Resource: !GetAtt Queue.Arn

  Integration:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      CredentialsArn: !GetAtt Role.Arn
      PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationSubtype: SQS-SendMessage
      RequestParameters:
        QueueUrl: !Ref Queue
        MessageBody: $request.body
        MessageAttributes: >-
          {
            "UserAgent": {
              "DataType": "String",
              "StringValue": "${request.header.user-agent}"
            }
          }

  Route:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Route
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
      RouteKey: $default
      Target: !Sub integrations/${Integration}
```

[image: Success deployment]

Comment: Well, that gives me some sort of relief.

I redacted some of the names from the serverless.yml configuration, but what exactly did you find not matching? If it's the resource name "RouteIntegration" in the error message, you can safely ignore that.

Are there ways to further debug this, rather than looking at Cloudformation stack events?